# SQL removing characters from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a datawarehouse task which needs replacing these characters:
`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` with nothing.

For example I have this form of data "`88k77.22`" and it should be "`8877.22`"

Does anyone know any particular function which can do this, or any workaround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Replace](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) and [Regex_replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: Replace with nothing, not with space... ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry, miss typo! I've edited it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '[A-Za-z]*', '')
```

Is '\' supposed to be included as well? Then use

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '[A-Za-z\]*', '')
```

Comment: \ is an escape character and it needs double slash to be escaped right?

Comment: @Simonare, not when it is inside a pair of brackets. `\s` matches whitespace but `[\s]` matches characters 's' and '\'

Answer (score 3):

Oracle supports [`translate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm), which does exactly what you want:

```
translate(col, ' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ' ')
```